# Box2D Flash 2.1 - Creating multiple bodies

Tags: box2d

I know how to create one body and add it to the world. But, say if I wanted to add lots of the same body to the world. How would I do that?

Comment: Put your 'create one body' code into a loop...?

Comment: You need to provide more details, show the code and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Simply - place your code into a loop and you will be happy.
**But**, if you want reuse your code later for other simple objects, and make your programming skills stronger, you should use **design patterns**, such as fabric methods.
In your case, write function which will take some parameters(body type, position, dimensions, etc.), and returns link to your new created body. This would solve your problem - You will have one function that does all staff for different body types(circles, polygons, convex).
Specially for your concrete problem - you should store body's parameters in  XML files for each level, then write method which would parse this parameters and would make you world full of bodies ;)
Enjoy!